# How to replace the (/) slash in the url?

Tags: php, http

I  would like to change the URL style like.
**example.com/abc/def
        to
example.com->abc->def**

Comment: This is not possible. You need at least one / after the domain name

Comment: Why we can't  change the  rule...

Comment: whats wrong with slash lol

Comment: I want to fly, we need to change the rules of gravity for that.

Comment: Accessing a website needs a domain name to resolve, knowing the difference between the domain name and the rest of the URI requires there to be a known character where the URI can be split (the slash). Changing that known character would require the entirety of the internet and the way it works to be changed.

Comment: Oh!  Come on  man decades of using same Things in the internet life.Small  changes could be cooler  Right.  @Andrew

Comment: What is the point of this question, if you don't mind me asking? Are you requiring this for something or what is the issue?

Comment: @vigneshwarar not cool when I have to type extra characters to just visit a particular section on a website, and on the phone I have to change to the symbol keypad just to type those characters...not very user friendly..imho

Comment: Yes @Rasclatt I am developing a Web application.For that I want to change this rule.Is there any way to do it.I think This kinda Cool.I am new to this Community.

Comment: No. As everyone is mentioning, you can not do it without at least the first `/` after the domain name: `www.example.com/test->is->best`

Comment: You cannot change the first slash, unless you are prepared to build your own internet (or browser) from scratch for just one website. Any slashes after the first you can change to whatever you want within the confines of typical URI rewriting.

Comment: @Andrew example.com/abc/def to example.com>abc>def.We can redirect   The normal slash Symbols  to our Required symbol.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = http://www.example.com/url/item/
var result = url.split('/').join('->');
window.replace(result);
```

Comment: Why don't you try that and see what happens?